# Unable to access the Name field value of a Lead

Tags: apex, trigger, leads

I am trying to do something like this but it is returning blank for lead.Name.

```
trigger Lead_SplitName on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
        lead.Last_Name__c = lead.Name;
    }
}
```

Whereas if I do `lead.email` returns the email and `lead.Company` return a value. What could be the cause?

Comment: use `lead.firstname + ' '  + lead.lastname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first i thought the issue is with before events because name is concatenation of firstname, middlename, lastname and suffix. But it turns out to be for after events as well.

I did a small test with the following code

Trigger:

```
trigger leadname on Lead (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    for(Lead lead : trigger.new){
        system.debug(lead.name);
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class leadnameTest {
    public static testmethod void test1() {
        Lead lead = new Lead(FirstName = 'F1',LastName = 'L1', Company = 'C1');
        Test.startTest();
        insert lead;
        lead = [select firstname,lastname,company,name from lead where id=: lead.Id];
        update lead;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

I got the below debugs. It comes null in all scenarios.

[image]

So we need to use concatenation of FirstName and LastName. If you enabled MiddleName and Suffix features, then concatenate those as well.

Hope it helps.